# Filtering a mutli-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | True | 89 |
|  | 9 | False | 77 |
|  | 5 | True | 23 |
| B | 9 | True | 45 |
|  | 5 | True | 45 |
|  | 2 | False | 78 |
| C | 11 | True | 10 |
|  | 8 | False | 08 |
|  | 12 | False | 09 |

C1 & C2 are the multi index. I'm hoping to get a result which gives me only values in C1 which have values both lower than 10 and greater than or equal to 10 in C2.

So in the table above C1 - B should go, with the final result should look like this:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | True | 89 |
|  | 9 | False | 77 |
|  | 5 | True | 23 |
| C | 11 | True | 10 |
|  | 8 | False | 08 |
|  | 12 | False | 09 |

I tried df.loc[(df.C2 < 10 ) & (df.C2 >= 10)] but this didn't work.

I also tried:

filter1 = df.index.get_level_values('C2') < 10
filter2 = df.index.get_level_values('C2') >= 10

df.iloc[filter1 & filter2]

Which I saw suggested on another post that also didn't work. Any one know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: kindly provide your dataframe as a dict: ``df.to_dict()``. Easier to replicate the MultiIndex

Comment: Is `(df.C2 < 10 ) & (df.C2 >= 10)` correct? Because it means all values

Comment: @jazrael That is what I want. Those with values above AND below. Not ones that have just below or just above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test at least one condition match per groups, so possible last filter by `m` DataFrame:

```
filter1 = df.index.get_level_values('C2') < 10 
filter2 = df.index.get_level_values('C2') >= 10

m = (df.assign(filter1= filter1, filter2=filter2)
       .groupby(level=0)[['filter1','filter2']]
       .transform('any'))

print (m)
       filter1  filter2
C1 C2                  
A  12     True     True
   9      True     True
   5      True     True
B  9      True    False
   5      True    False
   2      True    False
C  11     True     True
   8      True     True
   12     True     True
```

---

```
df = df[m.filter1 & m.filter2]
print (df)
          C3  C4
C1 C2           
A  12   True  89
   9   False  77
   5    True  23
C  11   True  10
   8   False   8
   12  False   9
```

Alternative solution:

```
filter1 = df.index.get_level_values('C2') < 10 
filter2 = df.index.get_level_values('C2') >= 10

lvl1 = df.index[filter1].remove_unused_levels().levels[0]
lvl2 = df.index[filter2].remove_unused_levels().levels[0]

df1 = df.loc[set(lvl1).intersection(lvl2)]
print (df1)
          C3  C4
C1 C2           
A  12   True  89
   9   False  77
   5    True  23
C  11   True  10
   8   False   8
   12  False   9
```